# dynamic ID for <input> html tag (file upload functionality), Watir

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have been trying to figure out how to upload a file using Watir for a while now.

Here is the HTML that I have to deal with

```
<div class="upload-csv">
     <label class="ng-binding">Upload .csv</label>
     <div file-upload="" id="upload-candidates-by-csv" on-file-added="add" on-success="success" on-failure="uploadfail" on-upload-start="uploadstart" config="upload.config" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope custom-file-upload" style="position: relative;">
           <button type="button" id="upload-candidates-by-csv-trigger" class="custom-file-upload-trigger" style="position: relative; z-index: 0;">Browse</button>
           <button type="button" ng-disabled="!canUpload" class="custom-file-upload-save" disabled="disabled">Upload</button>
     <div id="p18htertik11n414v95q6p6314603_html5_container" class="plupload html5" style="position: absolute; background-color: transparent; width: 220px; height: 50px; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; opacity: 0; top: 0px; left: 120px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
           <input id="p18htertik11n414v95q6p6314603_html5" style="font-size: 999px; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;" type="file" accept="text/csv">
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

So I tried to do this:

```
element_field = browser.file_field(:id, /html5\Z/)
element_field.set(params[:path_csv])
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:id=>/html5_\Z/, :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"file"} to become present
```

I also tried set value by class

```
class="plupload html5"
```

But set method does not work when element is found using class.

Would be happy to hear any input from the community. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want `browser.file_field(:id, /html5\Z/)` instead of `browser.file_field(:id, /html5_\Z/)`?

Comment: Thanks odre. That's what I had before I start experimenting. I still get the same error though. Any ideas or any other approaches?

Comment: It seems that the element you want exists, but it's not visible.  Running locally, `browser.file_field(:id, /html5\Z/).visible?` returns `false`.  So, you'll need to find the trigger that makes that <input> visible.

Comment: How does a user interact with that file upload? It looks like there is a custom browser button. You will likely need to interact with that rather than the file input directly.

Comment: Yes, there is a browser upload button. 

<button type="button" id="upload-candidates-by-csv-trigger" class="custom-file-upload-trigger" style="position: relative; z-index: 0;">Browse</button>

This triggers a window from the OS where you can select a file. Any ideas how to interact with that? May be there is a gem for that, @JustinKo?

Comment: What browser are you using? With the sample html and code, it seems to work just fine for me in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Hey @JustinKo I use FF right now.. Not sure what's going on to be honest.

Comment: If you test against a page that just has the sample html, do you get the same error? Perhaps there has to be more of the page for us to be able to reproduce your problem?